# Python Selenium Firefox - Insecure Connection Error Alert

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am using Python Selenium with FireFox and am struggling to resolve an issue.  Occasionally during a test script I come across a form that submits from https to http which throws this error...

```
The information you have entered on this page will be sent over an insecure connection and could be read by a third party
```

I have looked at using **driver.switchTo().alert().accept();** but it is not working, I assume it's because it's a FireFox generated alert rather than a java one from the site?  The error I receive is...

```
AttributeError: 'WebDriver' object has no attribute 'switchTo'
```

Anyone have any experience getting around the issue?

Comment: What do you mean "it is not working"?  How does it not work?  What is the behavior that you are seeing?

Comment: It throws an UnexpectedAlertPresentException

Comment: Ok, but then when you use the driver.switchTo().alert().accept() command, what happens?

Comment: op updated to make things clearer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Python, it is `switch_to`. Replace:

```
driver.switchTo().alert().accept();
```

with:

```
driver.switch_to.alert.accept()
```

<sup>Though, I am not sure this is a regular alert you can switch to this way. I suspect the behavior whether show the warning or not is controled via the specific firefox preference.</sup>

Comment: That seems to work great, thanks for that.  Now I just need to look into only triggering it if an alert is found